# Unable to create a fakes assembly for a SharePoint project

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-fakes

I've found that when trying to create a fakes assembly for a SharePoint project that references certain SharePoint libraries that I get errors similar to:

```
Failed to load properly Derived method 'RequiresWebPartClientScript' in type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ScriptWebPart' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' cannot reduce access.
```

This commonly occurs where the SharePoint project references libraries that are not in the GAC such as: **Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages** and **Microsoft.ApplicationPages.Administration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem is caused by the fakes generator being unable to resolve the reference when attempting to create fakes. The issue can be worked around by adding a reference to the offending library to the project that will contain the fakes assembly.

For example, if I have a project **'My.SharePoint.Stuff'** and I want to run tests in a project **'My.SharePoint.Stuff.Tests'** then I would generate a fakes assembly for **My.SharePoint.Stuff** in **My.SharePoint.Stuff.Tests**.

Where this fails as described above, the solution is to add a reference to the assembly that is described in the error message to the **My.SharePoint.Project.Tests** project and then recreate the fake.